# Change footer for some page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am making a page that have three main section and every section have a different footer. I also use a Litespeed caching to increase the page loading time. So that why i am want to use the recommended from the way of implementing different footer for different pages here is the [link](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:litemage:troubleshooting:separate-front-page-footer).
The problem is that when i remove the footer i can put the new one, the page is without footer. I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and i am disable all caching in the system and still no footer. Here is my xml code that i put in local.xml

```
<remove name="footer"/>
<reference name="root">
  <block type="page/html_footer" name="homefooter" as="footer" template="page/htm/homefooter.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="footer_top" as="footer_top" translate="label">
        <label>Footer Top</label>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="footer_bottom" as="footer_bottom" translate="label">
        <label>Footer Bottom</label>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_link">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>footer_social_link</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
    <reference name="footer_top">
      <block type="cms/block" name="footer_links">
        <action method="setBlockId">
          <block_id>footer_links</block_id>
        </action>
      </block>
    </reference>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error and it was in the example code. The problem is in the XML configuration, in the example. It is written this way

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="homefooter" as="footer" template="page/htm/homefooter.phtml">
```

The example code missed **L** from the **HTML** folder name. It need to be

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="homefooter" as="footer" template="page/html/homefooter.phtml">
```

I hope that this will be fixed so there is no one else spending so much time to search what is the problem.